# Apache Karaf bundle registration-listener registration-method never fires

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I am new to Apache Karaf, I am deploying a simple bundle which prints out the Date when it is started. I have achieved this using the Activator class and it calls the Activator start method and prints out the date. I was reading that there is another method I can achieve this without Activator and using the blueprint to register my service.

I have written the bundle and deployed it in Karaf container but it does not print out the date, it never even calls the register method as described below:

```xml
    <blueprint xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
        <bean id="timeGreetServiceImpl" class="com.cengage.wiring.TimeGreetServiceImpl">
            <argument ref="timeService"/>
            <argument ref="sampleService"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="serviceLaunch" class="com.cengage.wiring.ServiceLaunch"></bean>
        <reference id="sampleService" activation="eager" availability="mandatory" interface="com.cengage.api.SampleService">
        </reference>
        <reference id="timeService" activation="eager" availability="mandatory" interface="com.cengage.register.api.SimpleTimeService">
        </reference>
        <service id="timeGreetService" interface="com.cengage.wiring.TimeGreetService" ref="timeGreetServiceImpl">
            <registration-listener ref="serviceLaunch" registration-method="register" unregistration-method="unregister"/>
        </service>
    </blueprint>
```

This is my POJO class which has the register method

```java
public class ServiceLaunch {

    public void register(final TimeGreetService service) {
        System.out.println("TimeGreetService registered - output: "
                + service.print());
    }

    public void unregister() {

    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing ? There are no errors or logs on Karaf.

Thank You

Attempt 2:
As requested in the comments I changed my blueprint to but it still never hits the register method

```xml
<blueprint xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
<bean id="timeGreetServiceImpl" class="com.cengage.wiring.TimeGreetServiceImpl">
    <argument ref="timeService"/>
    <argument ref="sampleService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="serviceLaunch" class="com.cengage.wiring.ServiceLaunch"></bean>
<reference id="sampleService" activation="eager" availability="optional" interface="com.cengage.api.SampleService">
</reference>
<reference id="timeService" activation="eager" availability="optional" interface="com.cengage.register.api.SimpleTimeService">
</reference>
<service id="timeGreetService" interface="com.cengage.wiring.TimeGreetService" ref="timeGreetServiceImpl">
    <registration-listener ref="serviceLaunch" registration-method="register" unregistration-method="unregister"/>
</service>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Please ignore my first answer. I thought you were referencing the same service you publish. This is not the case so the optional is not necessary.

Comment: You can look into the services in karaf using the service:list <Interface> command. Does it show the services you depend on and maybe also the service you publish?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you are trying to register a service as type `TimeGreetService` but your class doesn't implement `TimeGreetService`. Also why do you care about the exact time that your own service is registered? Why not go for a simple activation method?

Comment: Hi Neil I am just trying to learn the blueprint method to register services because at work they use this method. Do you think my blueprint is wrong ?

Comment: @Christian yes they show as active bundles when I say list in my karaf terminal.

Comment: @alyn000r Okay that's fine, you're trying to learn how to register services with Blueprint, but why do you need a registration *listener*?

Comment: Honestly I never saw a registration listener before .. only a reference listener ... maybe it does not work at all. Will try to find a test for it in the blueprint code base.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I was just following this example http://www.hascode.com/2012/04/wiring-made-easy-using-osgi-blueprint-and-apache-karaf/  I believe this example has some errors with it. I will try your way would you guide me to an example please ?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I was trying to follow http://www.hascode.com/2012/04/wiring-made-easy-using-osgi-blueprint-and-apache-karaf/ if you have a better example please guide me. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remvoe the registration listener. You can then check if the service is registered using the karaf service:list command.

You can use the init-method and destroy-method attributes to get a callback when the service class is initialized. I have never seen a registration listener in all real life blueprint I have seen till now. So probably you will not need it.

If you need more blueprint examples take a look at the [karaf-tutorials](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials).

```
<blueprint xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">
    <bean id="timeGreetServiceImpl" class="com.cengage.wiring.TimeGreetServiceImpl">
        <argument ref="timeService"/>
        <argument ref="sampleService"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="serviceLaunch" class="com.cengage.wiring.ServiceLaunch"></bean>
    <reference id="sampleService" activation="eager" availability="mandatory" interface="com.cengage.api.SampleService">
    </reference>
    <reference id="timeService" activation="eager" availability="mandatory" interface="com.cengage.register.api.SimpleTimeService">
    </reference>
    <service id="timeGreetService" interface="com.cengage.wiring.TimeGreetService" ref="timeGreetServiceImpl"/>
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Blueprint solution seems to be highly convoluted, to achieve what should be a simple aim: registering a service and getting a callback when activated.

Here is an code sample in Declarative Services that does what I believe you are trying to do:

```
@Component
public class TimeGreetServiceImpl implements TimeGreetService {

   @Activate
   void activate() {
      System.out.printf("TimeGreet service registered, time now is %s%n", printTime());
   }

   @Override
   public String printTime() {
      // ...
   }

}
```

Note that when you run this, your component will not be activated until a service consumer tries to use the `TimeGreetService` service. This is because DS is lazy by default. If you like, you can change this by putting `immediate=true` in the attributes of the `@Component` annotation.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I am however trying to learn the blueprint method because thats what is being used at my work. I will research this method though do you know of any tutorial which explains this ? Also it does not matter about the time this is just an example which I was following.